# in memory database for trading app

Tags: database, in-memory-database, algorithmic-trading

I'm looking for in-memory database for trading application (so single microsec is extremely important) but with "delayed" dbms backend like postgresql if possible. Can you suggest anything please?

Thx
Marcin

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure: I work for the vendor of eXtremeDB.

eXtremeDB and TimesTen come to mind.

TimesTen can automatically synch with an Oracle backend.

eXtremeDB has an open replication scheme that allows you to synch to any backend (with some programming effort).

kdb+ would also probably meet your performance requirement, but synching to a backend would fall on you.

There might be other solutions: MySQL as an in-memory DB. Vertica. TBH, I don't know what would be involved to synch them to a backend; it seems like, though, that MySQL ought to be able to replicate between an in-memory instance and persistent instance. Maybe someone else can chime in.

Without knowing the details of how the database is accessed, it's impossible to say that any potential solution can meet the single-digit microsecond objective.

Comment: Hi Steven, thx for your input. What we're looking for is solution for storing trading data (intraday) with extreme fast access to it specially for HFT orders with some delayed access to relation database which can be used by other processes like reporting etc - so with regular sql interface

Comment: Hi Marcin, please feel free to contact me directly through any email link on the company website (in my profile).